# How to shorten the code: aiogram3, python?

Tags: python

**Hi all**, is there any way to condense the code? I intended to rewrite it from aiogram2 to aiogram3 but encountered an issue. I'm not sure how to make the code shorter (or more concise). I've also added JSON.
If someone has any ideas on how this can be phrased differently, I would be glad to listen.
**Aiogram3**:

```
@dp.message(F.text.lower() == "/austria")
async def AT(message: Message):
    with open("app/country_data.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    response = f'*{data["countries"]["AT"]["flag"]} The capital of {data["countries"]["AT"]["country"]}: {data["countries"]["AT"]["capital"]}*'
    await message.answer(response, parse_mode="Markdown")

    for place in data["countries"]["AT"]["places"]:
        caption = f'{place["number"]} *Place*: {place["name"]}\n* Description:*{place["about"]}\n\n  The link to the map: [Link]({place["on_map"]})'
        await message.answer_photo(
            photo=place["photo"], caption=caption, parse_mode="Markdown"
        )


@dp.message(F.text.lower() == "/albania")
async def AT(message: Message):
    with open("app/country_data.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    response = f'*{data["countries"]["AL"]["flag"]} The capital of {data["countries"]["AT"]["country"]}: {data["countries"]["AT"]["capital"]}*'
    await message.answer(response, parse_mode="Markdown")

    for place in data["countries"]["AL"]["places"]:
        caption = f'{place["number"]} *Place*: {place["name"]}\n* Description:*{place["about"]}\n\n  The link to the map: [Link]({place["on_map"]})'
        await message.answer_photo(photo=place["photo"], caption=caption)
```

**json**:

```
{
    "countries": {
        "AT": {
            "flag": "",
            "country": "Austria",
            "capital": "Vienna",
            "places": [
                {
                    "number": "1️⃣",
                    "name": "Schönbrunn Palace",
                    "about": "18th-century summer palace with tours of lavish rococo ceremonial rooms, plus gardens with a maze.",
                    "on_map": "https://goo.gl/maps/fyNJALFCPQBBa4kcA",
                    "photo": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipORKKbOMes0ObhtJ5RUMJdUDUL4CFLlvlaAfobK=w408-h272-k-no"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Aiogram2:**

**I had a countries.py file that contained all the "places" data.**

```
async def send_places(message, country_data):
    response = f"*{country_data['flag']} The capital of {country_data['country']}: {country_data['capital']}*"

    await message.answer(response, parse_mode="Markdown")

    await message.answer(
        "* Here are the 5 best places to visit:*", parse_mode="Markdown"
    )

    for number, place, description, url, image_url in country_data["places"]:
        await message.answer_photo(
            image_url,
            f"{number} *Place*: {place}\n* Description:* {description}\n\n The link to the map: [Link]({url})",
            parse_mode="Markdown",
        )

    await message.answer(
        "ℹ️ *Keep following my messages and you will learn about the most amazing places in the capitals of Europe!*",
        parse_mode="Markdown",
    )
    await message.answer("ℹ️ For more commands, you can use /help.")


# 
@dp.message_handler(commands=["Austria"])
async def Austria(message: types.Message):
    country_data = {
        "flag": "",
        "country": "Austria",
        "capital": "Vienna",
        "places": AT,
    }
    await send_places(message, country_data)


# 
@dp.message_handler(commands=["Albania"])
async def Albania(message: types.Message):
    country_data = {
        "flag": "",
        "country": "Austria",
        "capital": "Tirana",
        "places": AL,
    }
    await send_places(message, country_data)`
```

**If anything, I apologize for not writing the first question correctly.**